# Sum Up Query Values based on Same ID

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a bit confused and can't find the suitable solution. I wanna sum-up the values based on brand id

I have a products table that has a brand's ID as below

```
-----------------------------------
| id | quantity | low | brand_id | 
|----|----------|-----|----------|
|  1 |      100 | 100 |      1   |  
|  2 |       40 |  50 |      3   |  
|  3 |       10 |   5 |      2   |  
|  4 |       15 |  10 |      1   |  
|  5 |        6 |  10 |      2   |  
|  6 |        3 |  10 |      3   |
|  7 |       20 |  30 |      1   |
|----|----------|-----|---------|
```

I'm selecting all products with their values

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product WHERE brand = '" . (int)$brand_id . "'";
```

Then I run the function to get the "need" stock if "quantity" is less than "low" as below

```
foreach ($query->rows as $product) {
  if ($product['quantity'] < $product['low']) {
   $provalue =  $product['low'] - $product['quantity'];
  } else {
   $provalue = 0;
 }
}
```

Till now everything is going well the returning result showing:

```
----------------------------
|   brand_id   |   need    |
|--------------|-----------|
|       1      |    0      |
|       3      |    10     |
|       2      |    0      |
|       1      |    0      |
|       2      |    4      |
|       3      |    7      |
|       1      |    10     |
|--------------|-----------|
```

However I'm trying to sum the results of " need " based on " brand_id " to end up as following:

```
----------------------------
|   brand_id   |   need    |
|--------------|-----------|
|       1      |    10     |
|       2      |    4      |
|       3      |    17     |
|--------------|-----------|
```

Any suggestions please? Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this directly in your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT brand_id, SUM(GREATEST(0, low - quantity)) AS need
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product 
        GROUP BY brand_id";
```

We use `GREATEST` to ensure the values we sum are not negative when there is sufficient `quantity` to meet `low` (i.e. it's the equivalent of the `if` statement in your code).

Answer (score 1):

Change your sql query to below to compute need in query itself

```
$sql = "SELECT brand_id,SUM(low) -  SUM(quantity) As Need FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product 
        WHERE  quantity < low GROUP BY brand_id";
```